# Base controller, setting a private member variable, is this safe?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to create a base controller class that my other controllers will inherit from.  I have a simple public api that takes the authentication token via the query string, so I want to do this:

```
public class MyBaseController {
   private String token = "";
   public MyBaseController() {
   }
}
```

And then my real controller would be like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController extends MyBaseControler {

  // controller methods here
}
```

My question is, how can i get access to the HttpServletRequest in my base controller, and get the querystring parameter "?token=abc123" value and set the token var with the value.

Is this thread safe?  **It is my understanding that there will be a new controller instance per request correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controllers are better off if they're stateless.

You can inject them with Spring services as needed, but I don't see any reason why they have to hang onto the value of the token as a member variable.

It's far more likely that you'll want to store the token in session scope.  I think your idea is wrong-headed.

I'll point out that Spring itself has moved away from inheritance for controllers.  They're all annotation-based now, with no common base class or interface.  Why do you think devolving back to the design they abandoned is a good thing?

You don't need a base controller, either.

Comment: I agree, actually I was just thinking that I could use an interceptor,  and put the value in request scope if needed, but really I will load a different object based on the auth token that i need anyhow, thanks!

Comment: What?  The token is coming in with the request - it's already IN request scope.  Where else would it be?

Comment: what I meant was loading a different object in the interceptor, and then adding it to the request.